# UID for swift objects

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, uid

Is there any simple built-in way to generate unique idenitfiers for any in-app objects?(hash is not acceptable because it's ok in my situation to have objects with the same data) 
ID acceptable as either string or integer, only local uniqueness required.
Google doesn't help

Comment: Can you not just assign a unique identifier to your objects, using a custom class that manages them?

Comment: See, the [NSUUID Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/index.html).

Comment: Thanks, NSUUID seems to be exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need to do is determine if two objects that compare as equal with `==` are distinct, you can use the `===` operator:

```
let first = MyObject(value: 1)
let second = MyObject(value: 1)

first == second // returns true
first === second // returns false
```

If you really want to get a unique identifier, spelunking into the Swift standard library reveals:

```
/// Return an UnsafePointer to the storage used for `object`.  There's
/// not much you can do with this other than use it to identify the
/// object
func unsafeAddressOf(object: AnyObject) -> UnsafePointer<Void>
```

I make no claims as to the advisability of using that. It may not even work the way you think it will depending on copy-on-write shenanigans pulled by the compiler.

Comment: why not NSUUID from comments? I want something that won't change after recreating set of objects from file or network, for example, so I'm not sure that objects' addresses is the best solution...

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand what you needed, then, particularly when you said "only local uniqueness required."  Ah well...

Comment: I meant that only objects created in the same running app should have unique IDs...
Sorry for my English - can't tell what I need clear - haven't practiced it for a long time.